# Escape the ambigous riddles

Tags: riddle, story

You find yourself in a room. The walls, floor and ceiling are surrounded with steel. You notice on one side there is some unknown material, that is cool to the touch, and near the floor is a standard US electrical outlet. You also see a plaque on the opposite wall that says:

> Experiment Chamber/Respawn Room.
>   Rule 1: If you die, you respawn here.
>   Rule 2: Deaths do not reset riddle answers.

You open the door, eager to escape, but to your dismay there are only four more plaques and no new rooms. One plaque that appears to be a matte blue, on the wall to your left reads:

> I have a mouth, but do not speak.

The one straight ahead appears to be a goldish color, but is hard to tell in the light. It reads:

> I may arrest you, or conduct you.

The one to your left seems almost velvet, but feels cool and mettalic to the touch and mysteriously reads:

> Decipher me: gzderfk.

The final one, which is less a plaque, as much as a neon sign, reads:

> Riddle room.
>   Rule 3: Each riddle may be answered to create as much of that answer as you desire, where you desire, but once you have chosen a location and amount you may not recreate that object.
>   Rule 4: You may not use clever word play to escape.
>   Rule 5: Until you escape, death is a temporary thing.
>   Your only hint: There is nothing beyond these wall besides open air and the ground. But no one will come to save you.

What do you do to escape? (Yes, you want to escape and no, you do not want to die.)

Comment: What is stuck in my head is the mouth and do not speak and I think it is a rot13 ( evire) but how can it arrest you?

Comment: @Duck the plaques are seperate riddles.

Comment: Is it right then?

Answer (score 1):

> Tunnels have mouths but do not speak. I'll create a tunnel through one of the walls and walk out...?

Comment: I'll wait 24 hours for a better answer and if one does not appear I'll select yours as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

I have a mouth, but do not speak.

> This is a common riddle that refers to a River.

I may arrest you, or conduct you.

> As @stuartstevenson said, I believe this is Copper.

Decipher me: gzderfk.

> I haven't figured it out yet. It's not a Caeser/Shift Cipher (at least, not one that produces an obvious word.

What to do:

> Once broken out of the enclosure (Method TBD), I would create a copper canoe and a river that I can use to escape.

Answer (score 0):

> I may arrest you, or conduct you.

This must be...

> Copper.

Comment: Please hide the suggested answer with >! - I tried to edit, but it wouldn't let me unless I changed 6 or more characters. Since there is only 1 to change, I didn't mess up your post just to be able to save it.